# Best Practice for Adding WCF Web Service to Existing Web site

Tags: asp.net, wcf, web-services

I have searched quite a bit for coverage of this topic and can’t find very much on it.

If I have a website (intranet to my company)   MySite.company.com/
And I want to implement a web service associated with that website {GetProductDetails.svc}

Can I make the URL (endpoint) for accessing the services something like: 
MySite.company.com/Services/GetProductDetails.svc 
I want to keep the base address the same and not have to direct users of the service to some other address.

I have been told it would need to be something like this (basically a separate web site):
MySite.company.com:1858/GetProductDetails.svc

Or should I create a separate site like this:
MySiteServices.company.com/GetProductDetails.svc

Comment: if it's under the same application in IIS, then `MySite.company.com/Services/GetProductDetails.svc` will work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your service is within a **service** folder in your existing website, then the url `MySite.company.com/Services/GetProductDetails.svc` will work.  Depending on the .NET version you're using, you will need to specify the service bindings in the `web.config` of the current website.

If you are only exposing Product Details, and this is over `HTTP` to other applications, you could also use a `Web API`, [Learn Web API](http://www.asp.net/web-api).

Comment: I will pursue those options.  Thank you